# Missing $ inserted |

Tags: templates, missing, program

I am using this template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq

my equation is:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
\jyear{2021}%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%
\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
J(A, B)=\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}
\end{equation}


\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
\end{document}
```

The same problem with:

```
\begin{equation}
dh_{i}=\left|h_{t l}-h_{i}\right|
\end{equation}
```

it gives an error and doesn't show `|` in the equation.

Comment: Please try to post a complete example; with `article` your equations works ok. Are you sure you did not load some package that changes the meaning of `|`? Some verbatim-like packages do that, I think. This is the reason why an MWE is so important in LaTeX... https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes

Comment: Something is strange, I used it after your comment without any addition or change. The same issue.

Comment: Unrelated: remember that generally `|... |` is not the proper symbol pair to use (try `|-1|`, the minus spacing is wrong). Use `amssymb` and `\lvert... \rvert` instead

Comment: @daleif, Thank you so much. It is working fine now.

Comment: You should still provide a full minimal example such that your question is usable for others in the future. So far we have no idea what you're doing that might cause `|` to behave differently

Comment: @daleif, I updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For very mysterious reasons, the class loads `program.sty`, an obscure package that does several mysterious things and has essentially no documentation: one page with no examples; it tells to look into `program-demo.tex`, which is pretty uninformative as well.

On the other hand, the scanty documentation for the package tells users to use `origbar` instead of `|`.

You should complain with the editors and the maintainers of the class, because forcing users to deal with this package is really awful of them. By the way, the class also loads `algpseudocode`, which is ***much*** better than `program`. What I find most irritating is that the package redefines `\(` and `\)`.

Anyway, you can solve your problem by using `\lvert` and `\rvert` which are actually better than the unadorned `|` to denote absolute value or cardinality. LaTeX also provides `\vert` as an alias.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style

\jyear{2021}

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
J(A, B)=\frac{\lvert A \cap B\rvert}{\lvert A \cup B\rvert}
\end{equation}


\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more drastic step would be to undo the (wrong) settings made by `program.sty`.

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
\jyear{2021}%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%
\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\raggedbottom

%%% Undo the settings made by program.sty
\catcode`_=8 % _ is subscript
\catcode`|=12 % | is a normal character
\mathcode`;=\semicolon
\mathcode``=``
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\({\relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand\){\relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}
\makeatother
%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
J(A, B)=\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}
\end{equation}


\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `sn-jnl` class load the package `program` causing the problem. Commenting out or removing the line #311 (`\usepackage{program}%`) of `sn-jnl.sty` gives the correct result.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
\jyear{2021}%
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%
\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{equation}
        J(A, B)=\frac{|A \cap B|}{|A \cup B|}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}
        dh_{i}=\left\|h_{t l}-h_{i}\right\|  % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    \end{equation}
    
%   \bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
\end{document}
```