# How to write the following on overleaf?

Tags: springer, springernature

I am trying to write the following expression in Overleaf

[image]

However, I am facing issues with the following code.

`J= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left| y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right|^{2}`

This code works on Lyx (which I generally use), also works on online Latex equation generators. But not on Overleaf.

This is the code I used in Overleaf:

```
\begin{equation}
    J= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left| y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right|^{2}
\end{equation}
```

This is output I get in Overleaf:
[image]

I am not a programmer and I don't understand Latex in very detail. Here, are the errors

Error 1:

```
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.198     J= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left|
                                              y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right|^{2}
I was expecting to see something like `(' or `\{' or
`\}' here. If you typed, e.g., `{' instead of `\{', you
should probably delete the `{' by typing `1' now, so that
braces don't get unbalanced. Otherwise just proceed.
Acceptable delimiters are characters whose \delcode is
nonnegative, or you can use `\delimiter <delimiter code>'.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.198 ...}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left| y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right
                                                  |^{2}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

Error 2:

```
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.198 ...\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left| y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right|
                                                  ^{2}
I was expecting to see something like `(' or `\{' or
`\}' here. If you typed, e.g., `{' instead of `\{', you
should probably delete the `{' by typing `1' now, so that
braces don't get unbalanced. Otherwise just proceed.
Acceptable delimiters are characters whose \delcode is
nonnegative, or you can use `\delimiter <delimiter code>'.

! Extra \right.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.198 ...\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left| y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right|
                                                  ^{2}
I'm ignoring a \right that had no matching \left.
```

Error 3:

```
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).

Learn more
<inserted text> 
                $
l.198 ...\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left| y_{i}-{y}_{i}\right|
                                                  ^{2}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endmathdisplay@a ...\df@tag \@empty \else \veqno 
                                                  \alt@tag \df@tag \fi \ifx ...
l.199 \end{equation}
```

Error 4:

```
<inserted text> 
                \right .
l.199 \end{equation}
                    
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

I seriously don't know what these things mean.

Comment: This is not related to overleaf, but presumably in code you have not shown us you have defined `|` to have a special meaning so it can no longer be used in math. Use `\left\lvert...\right\rvert` instead (normally his does the same as `|` but will still work even if you have changed `|`)

Comment: It always helps if you make your examples small but complete documents that show the problem.

Comment: Well it is the Springer Nature template. I didn't modify anything. Just wrote some equations and this one gives me error. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq

Comment: well as I say you can use `\lvert` and `\rvert` in place of `|` and `|` I may look later what the templateis doing

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: sorry I should have remembered this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619280/springer-nature-2021-class-causes-error-when-writing-x/619283#619283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might follow egreg's answer [how to undo program.sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634122/161015)   to override the package `program` actions loaded by `sn-jnl` class or use `\origbar`.

```
\begin{equation}
    J= \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\origbar y_{i}-{y}_{i}\origbar^{2}
\end{equation}
```

[image: x]

Comment: ah I thought that looked familiar Id eeven answered it before:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619280/springer-nature-2021-class-causes-error-when-writing-x/619283#619283

Comment: @David Carlisle Yours is a much better answer.